# Not extracting json properly using json4s

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I have a json:

```
{"key1":["12345"],"key2":[{"key3":"some value"}]}
```

I need to extract the value for key3

When I am doing `compact(render(json \ "key2" \ "key3"))`

I am getting a string with the square bracket ["some value"].
Please let me know how to get only value as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do so, using the [`apply`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3f920f4a111f67031005a996c53bad67d8eda716/ast/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JsonAST.scala#L169) method on the `JArray`:

```scala
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

val json = parse("""{"key1":["12345"],"key2":[{"key3":"some value"}]}""")
(json \ "key2" )(0) \ "key3"
// res6: JValue = JString("some value")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`\\`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/11b8b4ab31703600a31fb0f48554e15de2d1550f/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/MonadicJValue.scala#L73) which  returns all matching fields by name. For example

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

object Hello extends App {
  val json = parse("""{"key1":["12345"],"key2":[{"key3":"some value"}]}""")
  println(json \\ "key3")
}
```

should output `JString(some value)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods

val x =
  """{"key1":["12345"],"key2":[{"key3":"some value"}]}
    | """
val key3 =  JsonMethods.parse(x) \ "key2" \ "key3"
val list = (key3.values)
println(list)
```

Would print 
List(some value)